# Detect hyperlink in RichTextBox when symbol is @ or #

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, twitter, richtextbox

I'm developing wp8 application for reading Twitter. I read, that `RichTextBox` can detect links, it's good. But, I want to make next functionality: if in tweet text exist symbol "@" - make a hyperlink with world after "@", which will open a new page like `/DetailsPage.xaml?name=@name` and show additional info about user. The same thing with #, but open page with tweets which has this hashtag. Is there any way to make it?

Comment: [Here][1] I found the best way how to implement RichTextBox with links.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959137/bind-text-with-links-to-richtextbox/12961621#12961621

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, use the following XAML:

```
<RichTextBox>
    <Paragraph>
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="/Page1.xaml">click me!</Hyperlink>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

This will display text click me! which looks like a hyperlink and can be clicked. When clicked, it will take you to Page1.xaml in your project.

You will obviously need to create content dynamically for RichTextBox, but I will leave it as an exercise.

Comment: Seriously? It's the best way?

Comment: How else would you do it? You need to mark the text as link, like using Hyperlink tag above, and set its Uri to something.

Comment: maybe RichTextBox's triggers or behavior? Can you show example for string "Checking out the new @diradio stations. This new group looks awesome"? If I understand, I need to `Split` all message, and then if first symbol world's is "@" make hyperlink, but how?

Comment: You will need Regex for replacing it. Something like Regex.Replace(s, "@[^\s]*", string.Format(...));

Comment: Thanks, but I fouded complete solution, I've posted it in comment to question