# Binding to RichTextBox Blocks property

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8

I would like to bind directly to the Blocks property of a `RichTextBox` in my Xaml.  This is not possible as the `Blocks` property is read only.  I can bind directly to an individual run:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="MyRichTextBox" FontSize="36" Margin="10" Foreground="White">
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="{Binding MyObject.Text}" Foreground="Yellow"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding MyObject.Text}" Foreground="Cyan"/>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

I would like to do something like:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="MyRichTextBox" Blocks="{Binding MyObject.RichTextBlocks}" FontSize="36" Margin="10" Foreground="White"/>
```

Particularly as I don't know in advance how many blocks will be returned from the binding object.

Is the correct way to achieve this to create an *Attached Behaviour* for the `RichTextBox` with a `RichTextBlocks` property that when being set enumerates through the blocks and calls `RichTextBox.Blocks.Add()` for each one?

I am new to C#, .NET and XAML so please excuse the elementary question and a simply explained answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there is no OOTB solution for this - thus any solution from WP7 is good to go. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959137/bind-text-with-links-to-richtextbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the pointers from @Nogard and the other post, I created my own class with a *Dependency Property* called `RichText`.  Have posted here in case it is of use to anyone else.

```
  public class MyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RichTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RichText", typeof(Paragraph), typeof(MyRichTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(null, RichTextPropertyChanged));

        public Paragraph RichText
        {
            get 
            { 
                return (Paragraph)GetValue(RichTextProperty); 
            }

            set 
            { 
                SetValue(RichTextProperty, value); 
            }
        }

        private static void RichTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            MyRichTextBox richTextBox = (MyRichTextBox)dependencyObject;
            Paragraph paragraph = (Paragraph)dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue;

            // Remove any existing content from the text box
            richTextBox.Blocks.Clear();

            // Add the paragraph to the text box
            richTextBox.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        }
    }
}
```

and added this to my xaml...

```
<sub:MyRichTextBox x:Name="MyRichTextOverlay" RichText="{Binding CurrentOverlay.RichTextParagraph}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" Margin="10" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```