# trying to add and display hyperlink to string property of an object

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an object which currently has a property that is a `String` and is being populated in code behind. This property is then bound to a textblock, and currently displays exactly as expected in the app.
What I want to do is have certain words within the string as hyperlinks, which will navigate to another page when tapped, but I am having trouble achieving this.

I thought I had it figured out when I changed the property to a `Paragraph` instead of `String`, and added the text/hyperlink as `Inlines`, but then when I bind the textblock to the Paragraph it displays the `.ToString()` value, not the content expected.

Am I going about this correctly? Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Code added;
Here is my object creation (if I just add a string to `AbilityEffect` then it works fine as noted above), with two methods of trying to get a hyperlink working, neither of which is achieving what I want;

```
Paragraph tempparagraph = new Paragraph();
tempparagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run {Text = "Each turn the model may count one "});
tempparagraph.Inlines.Add(CreateActionHyperlink("Climb"));
tempparagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run {Text = " or one "});
tempparagraph.Inlines.Add(CreateActionHyperlink("Sprint"));
tempparagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run {Text = " action as a short action instead of a long actioin. The model may take a "});
tempparagraph.Inlines.Add(CreateActionHyperlink("Move"));
tempparagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run {Text = " action as normal."});
data.Abilities.Add(new Abilities_data
{
    AbilityName = "Agile",
    AbilityEffect = "Each turn the model may count one " + new HyperlinkButton
    {
        Content = "Climb",
        NavigateUri = new Uri("/Views/Actions_Data.xaml?name=Climb", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    }
    + " or one " + new HyperlinkButton
    {
        Content = "Sprint",
        NavigateUri = new Uri("/Views/Actions_Data.xaml?name=Sprint",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    }
    + " action as a short action instead of a long action. The model may take a " + new HyperlinkButton
    {
        Content = "Move",
        NavigateUri = new Uri("/Views/Actions_Data.xaml?name=Move",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    }
    + " action as normal.",
        AbilityEffect2 = tempparagraph    
    });
```

and the CreateAction method;

```
private Hyperlink CreateActionHyperlink(string actionname)
{
    Hyperlink linky = new Hyperlink();
    linky.Inlines.Add(actionname);
    linky.NavigateUri = new Uri("/Views/Actions_Data.xaml?name=" + actionname,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    return linky;
}
```

And my xaml binding;

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AbilityEffect2}"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Which outputs `System.Windows.Documents.Paragraph` instead of the content

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I have added my code. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Paragraph` elements do not work with `TextBlock`. You need to use `RichTextBox`. You need to set its `IsReadOnly` property to true, else `Hyperlink` won't be active. Also, you need to add this `Paragraph` to the `Blocks` property of `RichTextBox`. `Blocks` is not a dependency property, so you cannot use data binding with it.

You can do it this way:

```
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="rtb"/>
```

and

```
Paragraph tempparagraph = new Paragraph();
tempparagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "Each turn the model may count one " });
tempparagraph.Inlines.Add(CreateActionHyperlink("Climb"));
.........

rtb.Blocks.Add(tempparagraph);
```

EDIT:

You can take a look at this example: [Bind text with links to RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959137/bind-text-with-links-to-richtextbox). It uses a derived version of `RichTextBox` and adds a data bindable `Text` property.

EDIT 2:

On second thought, I think you can do the following to make minimal change to your existing code:

(1) Use a `RichTextBlock` as before

```
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="rtb"/>
```

(2) Add a handler for `PropertyChanged` event of your viewmodel in cs file for your page.

```
(this.DataContext as Abilities_data).PropertyChanged += OnAbilitiesdataPropertyChanged;
```

(3) If `AbilityEffect2` property changes, add it to `RichTextBlock`.

```
void OnAbilitiesdataPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "AbilityEffect2")
    {
        rtb.Blocks.Clear();
        rtb.Blocks.Add((sender as Abilities_data).AbilityEffect2);
    }
}
```

I might have got the structure of your viewmodel wrong, but you get the idea.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try it out later this evening. Is this the best/only way to achieve a block of text with hyperlinks though? From my (admittedly limited) understanding of WPF, it seems a little counter intuitive to need to either use a read only input control that doesn't support binding, or create your own version and shoehorn binding in. I would have thought that MS had an easier way to do this....

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it. However, I have found a simpler approach. See the "EDIT 2" portion of my updated answer.